# Install Ubuntu 8.04 in triple-boot with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 8.04

No, this isn't the typical duplicate question about dual Ubuntu (12+) with Windows 8. I am way past that, dual booting beautifully Ubuntu 14.04 LTS & Windows 8.1, thanks to [this excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/228069/363039) (although I didn't have to resort to all of tricks described there, my install went very simply and smoothly).

My questions is whether it is possible at all to install Ubuntu `8.04` (Hardy Heron) on a UEFI system?

Does the fact that I already have grub installed and working (booting Windows 8.1 as well) provide better chance for accomplishing this?

Are there any caveats or tricks that I should be aware of before attempting to try this?

Comment: Why would you be interested in installing and running an no longer supported Ubuntu release?

Comment: @xangua Excellent question. Solely for running VMWare workstation 6.5 for which I paid and I do not wish to pay an additional $150 for an upgrade. All I want is run a lean & mean VMWare workstation 6.5 under Ubuntu 8.04.  If Ubuntu 14 had a "compatibility mode" I would have gladly use it, but my attempts at running VMWare 6.5 on a higher version of Ubuntu did not fair well.

Comment: Then dump vmware and use open source software for your virtualization needs.

Comment: @psusi I have 50+ VMs that it would take forever to convert. I tried converting them to VirtualBox using [ovftool](http://www.howtogeek.com/125640/how-to-convert-virtual-machines-between-virtualbox-and-vmware/) but the results were unusable (VM simply won't boot). I tried using them on the free VMPlayer 7, they won't boot either. They only work on VMWare 6.5. Which open source do you recommend and how do I convert my VMs to it? Thanks.

Comment: I use qemu at home for testing and xen on servers.  A quick google came up with: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_To_Migrate_From_Vmware_To_KVM

Comment: @psusi Unfortunately, the VMware-to-QEMU/KVM migration instructions [did not work for me](http://askubuntu.com/a/571556/363039). I think that I am going to stick with VMware. If this thread is re-opened, I will post a detailed `how to install VMWare Workstaton 6.x in Ubuntu 14.04` based on [these tips](http://dandar3.blogspot.cz/2014/01/vmware-player-601-on-ubuntu-1404-alpha.html).