# qemu: "not a bootable disk"

Tags: 14.04, kvm-virtualization, qemu, vmware-workstation

So I followed exactly the instructions on how to run QEMU-KVM with VMware's disk images v6 directly:

```
  kvm -drive file=zimbra-000001.vmdk,boot=on -net nic,macaddr=00:0c:29:c3:93:b9 -net tap -uuid 564d3f3d-3280-5bf2-9431-21c9b2c393b9
```

(replacing the various parameters with my own, of course, after looking them up in the VMX configuration file)

And instead of seeing the VM starting (as I am used to from my VMWare Workstation 6.5, running on an older Ubuntu), I receive:

```
Boot failed:  not a bootable disk
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. Is there anything else that I needed to do before attempting this shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it assumes that the drive is of type `RAW`, but it looks like you're using `vmdk`. I would check the disk type in the machine's current config and make sure that it is trying to read a disk of type `vmdk`

Comment: Thanks. Your answer allowed me to proceed to booting, seeing the nice Starting Windows 7 logo and then... the BSOD: *A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer. BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO*. Technical information: `STOP: 0x00000074 (0x00000002,0x86973BA8,0x00000002,0xC000009A)`

Comment: Same exact set of files (unmodified) continues to open perfectly with VMWare Player 7. Looks like [QEMU-KVM's claims to native support to VMware's disk images v6](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_To_Migrate_From_Vmware_To_KVM) have been exaggerated.

Comment: `kvm-img convert -O qcow2` conversion completes successfully but upon running the VM, it generates the same exact BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO error. I think I am going to [stick with VMWare](http://dandar3.blogspot.cz/2014/01/vmware-player-601-on-ubuntu-1404-alpha.html), pointed to it via [this howto](http://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/how-to-install-vmware-player-in-ubuntu-14-04/).